# ImageMagick convert error (Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 70)

Tags: ruby, linux, configuration, ubuntu, imagemagick

Looks like it is reading the wrong jpeg ibrary, but I have jpeg 7 installed. How do i tell ImageMagick to look up the right JPEG library version(I don't care 62 or 70 as long as it works).

[here](http://computerplumber.com/2009/01/installing-rmagick-28-gem-on-hardy/) is the instruction i am following